# Stash list, conditionals, and {count}

Tags: stash, conditionals

I'm using Stash lists to output channel entries grouped by the value of a custom field. In this case the custom field is a relationship field, but that's not relevant because the actual entries output is working just fine. What *is* giving me problems is using the {count} variable to apply a heading to each group of entries. Here's my code (for simplicity I've removed most of the variables that I'm stashing and just including the 'reviewtext' one).

```
<!-- STASH variables -->
{exp:channel:entries channel="reviews" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" show_expired="yes" cache="yes" refresh="10"}
    {exp:stash:append_list name="entries" context="{reviews_assigned_project:channel_short_name}" parse_conditionals="yes"}
        {stash:reviewtext}{reviews_review}{/stash:reviewtext}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}

<!-- book reviews -->
{exp:stash:get_list name="entries" context="books" process="end"}
    {if {count} == 1}
        <h2>Book reviews</h2>
    {/if}
    <article>
        {reviewtext}
        {count} of {total_results}
    </article>
{/exp:stash:get_list}

<!-- comic reviews -->
{exp:stash:get_list name="entries" context="comics" process="end"}
    {if {count} == 1}
        <h2>Comic book reviews</h2>
    {/if}
    <article>
        {reviewtext}
        {count} of {total_results}
    </article>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The output is fine apart from the conditional, which is output verbatim, with the exception that the value of {count} is parsed into the page. So, when I have three book reviews and two comic reviews, I get the following:

```
<!-- book reviews -->
{if 1 == 1}
    <h2>Book reviews</h2>
{/if}
<article>
    ... my entry content ...
    1 of 3
</article>

{if 2 == 1}
    <h2>Book reviews</h2>
{/if}
<article>
    ... my entry content ...
    2 of 3
</article>

{if 3 == 1}
    <h2>Book reviews</h2>
{/if}
<article>
    ... my entry content ...
    3 of 3
</article>

<!-- comic reviews -->
{if 1 == 1}
    <h2>Comic book reviews</h2>
{/if}
<article>
    ... my entry content ...
    1 of 2
</article>

{if 2 == 1}
    <h2>Comic book reviews</h2>
{/if}
<article>
    ... my entry content ...
    2 of 2
</article>
```

I've tried wrapping the conditional in exp:ifelse tags, and I've tried using Switchee instead of the {if} conditional. In every case the conditional tags (of whatever sort, including the ifelse and switchee tags) are output as template code. I tried stashing the count as a variable but that gives me the count from the entire channel entries tag rather than the count of the list output - so my book reviews have counts of 1, 3 and 4, whilst my comic reviews have counts of 2 and 5. Not what I'm after.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the stash:list's count to work in the conditional statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding parse_conditionals="yes" to your get_list. I think the issue is parse order for the conditionals on the get_list because you are using process="end". Does this work (I also added a prefix parameter for the count):

```
<!-- book reviews -->
{exp:stash:get_list 
    name="entries" 
    context="books"
    parse_tags="yes" 
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    prefix="st"
    process="end"
}
    {if {st:count} == 1}
        <h2>Comic book reviews</h2>
    {/if}
    etc....
```

Comment: Romans-8---31-39: That did it! I hadn't realised that parse_conditionals could be used on the Get tags -- I don't think the documentation mentions it. But simply adding that parameter got the conditional to process properly, and I didn't need the prefix either. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it was removed from the tag documentation for some reason, but is used in some examples. Not sure if that's an accident or things are changing - maybe if Mark Croxton runs across this he'll chime in.